# I am trying to implement a back propagation algorithm in python using Relu activation fuction

Tags: python

I am trying to implement the back propagation algorithm in python using the Relu activation function but in the relu derivative function the error is occurred and I am not getting that.

I have some error which in the relu_derivative function. I am attaching here the screenshot of that:

[image]

```
print ('Back Propagation algorithm in Python')
    import numpy as np 
    # RELU activation function
    def ReLU(z):
        a= np.maximum(0,z[0])
        b= np.maximum(0,z[1])
        c= np.maximum(0,z[2])
        d= np.maximum(0,z[3])
        return([a,b,c,d])



    def relu_derivative(z):
        d=[]
        e=[]
       if z[0]==0 or z[0]<0:
          d.append(0)
       else:
          e.append(1)
       if z[1]==0 or z[1]<0:
          d.append(0)
       else:
          e.append(1)
       if z[2]==0 or z[2]<0:
          d.append(0)
       else:
          e.append(1)
       if z[3]==0 or z[3]<0:
          d.append(0)
       else:
          e.append(1)
       [enter image description here][2]return(np.array(d,e))
    training_inputs = np.array([[0,0,1],
                                [1,1,1],
                                [1,0,1],
                                [0,1,1]])
    training_outputs = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T
    np.random.seed(1)
    synaptic_weights = 2*np.random.random((3,1))-1
    print('Random Starting synaptic weights: ')
    print(synaptic_weights)

    for iteration in range(100):
        input_layer = training_inputs
        outputs=ReLU(np.dot(input_layer,weights))
        error=training_outputs-outputs
        adjustments=error*relu_derivative(outputs)
        synaptics_weights=synaptic_weights + np.dot(input_layer.T,adjustments)

    print('weights after training:')
    print(synaptic_weights)

    print('Outputs after training:')
    print(outputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the errors in your codes:

- First, You forgot to initialize weights in

  ```
  weights=weights + np.dot(input_layer.T,adjustments)
  ```

you might want to initialize it outside the loop.

- Also, if we look at `relu_derivative(z)`, you did not define e, f, g, h in advance but you are returning [e,f,g, h]. You might like to initialize e,f,g,h in the first line of your function definition.
- Also, take note of the input to `relu_derivative`, `z[0]` is not a single number.
- Also, the length of `z[0]` seems to be 3 and not 4 currently.